# how to keep android wear app on after screen timeout

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, wear-os

I am writing an app which takes alot of time to load because of multiple ajax requests. The problem is that the screens timeout before finishing loading. this means that if I don't tap on the screen while loading, the screen will timeout and the app closes.

My question:
**How can I make the app stay open even after the screen timeout?**

I know that I can block the timeout and keep the screen on, but thats not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: unfortunately wear devices have low battery life, so this functionality is I guess limited. Even with always-on apps the screen ambient is around 15 seconds. I am also looking for the same thing. Will keep you posted if I find something. good luck

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're hoping to have happen on the watch? What would you envision as the UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the app open, the standard method for doing this on Android wear is to simply enable ambient support in you app (doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html)), and you can grab a processor wakelock for any work that you need to keep processing in the background, which will at least save some battery for keeping the screen fully on.

That said, if the time it takes to load your app is longer than the ambient timeout, you might have to rethink the amount of data you're trying to download. Maybe you can clarify on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!